# iterating through a vector of struct elements

Tags: c++, vector

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    node *parent;
    int x, y;
    float f, g, h;
    };
node findmin(vector<node> open)
{
    int mini=2000000;
    node iter,mininode;

    std::vector<node>::iterator it;
    for(it = open.begin(); it != open.end(); ++it) {
        if(it.f<mini)
            {
                mini=it.f;
                mininode=it;
            }
    }
    return mininode;
}
int main() {

    vector<node> open;
    vector<node> closed;

    node start;
    start.x=50;
    start.y=50;
    start.f=0;
    start.g=0;
    start.h=0;// you can take it as zero. works instead of the actual distnace between goal and start.

    node goal;
    goal.x=53;
    goal.y=50;
    goal.f=-1;
    goal.g=-1;
    goal.h=0;

    // put the starting node on the open list
    open.push_back(start);


    node current,temp;
    current=findmin(open);
   // THE EDIT CODE GOES HERE.

    return 0;
}
```

Somehow the iteration thru all vector elements is not working. My struct is `node`. `open` is a vector of `node` elements. I am trying to iterate thru all the `node` elements in `findmin` function.
Can correction be suggested along with reason?

**EDIT:**

Now suppose i want to use this function like this by putting following lines appropriately in main() in above code:

```
node current,temp;
current=findmin(open);
cout<<current.f;

for(vector<node>::iterator it = open.begin(); it != open.end(); ++it) {
    if(*it==current)
        {
            open.erase(*it);
        }

    }
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Remember that iterators are modeled to be similar to pointers, so you have to dereference them properly, like e.g. `it->f`. Or maybe use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: What halfwitted compiler that you are using, compiles this?

Comment: `it->f` works but i have another issue. refer EDIT above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Next time provide more information for your question. You need to be more specific, tell is it compile errors, or runtime and what errors occured.
2. Fix your `findmin` function

   ```
   node findmin( vector<node> open ) {
       int mini = 2000000;
       node iter, mininode;

       std::vector<node>::iterator it;
       for( it = open.begin( ); it != open.end( ); ++it ) {
           if( it->f<mini ) {
               mini = it->f;
               mininode = *it;
           }
       }
       return mininode;
   }
   ```
3. Do not pass `vector<node>`. Pass its reference (or better constant reference). Because in your example vector will be copied. And use `const_iterator`.

   ```
   node findmin( const vector<node>& open ) { /**/ }
   ```
4. Do `erase` in the loop like this

   ```
   for (vector<node>::iterator it = open.begin(); it != open.end(); /* ++it*/) {
     if(*it == current) 
        it = open.erase(it);
     else 
        ++it;
   }
   ```

   But you will need to overload `operator==`, or write some other condition in `if` statement.

Comment: So it was a compile error. Also pls solve my other query in EDIT section above.

Comment: should work but don't know why it is giving following error: `no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'node' and 'node' )`

Comment: @userxigy I already mentioned that (look at the last line in answer). If you need to overload operator you can do it for example as follows ``bool operator==(const node& n1, const node& n2) { return n1.x == n2.x && n1.y == n2.y; }``

Comment: I wrote: `if((it->x == current.x) &&(it->y == current.y))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why `!open.empty()` should evaluate to `false`, because the "open" vector is not being affected in the loop body. So you have an infinite loop in your main. I think this is the error.